# ¿Cómo puedo hacer este procedimiento almacenado con una transacción para que se actualice la cuenta cada que se haga un deposito?

Tags: sql

-Crear un procedimiento almacenado llamado deposito, donde por medio de una transaccion actualize la tabla cuenta cada vez que se haga un deposito.
Si hay error hacer rollback si no commit.

```
alter proc deposito (@deposito money) as begin
begin tran
set @deposito = (select * from cuenta)+@deposito
if exists(select monto from cuenta) begin
print 'Error'
rollback
end
else
commit
end
go

exec deposito 10000
```

Comment: Qué es lo que has intentado? Cuál es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios problemas en el procedimiento que muestras y en la poca información que aportas.

```
Create table Cuenta (id int, monto money);
```

¿`Cuenta` puede tener más de una fila? Si la respuesta es afirmativa, entonces el procedimiento debería de recibir el identificador de la fila de la cuenta que se quiere actualizar.

```
create or alter proc deposito (@deposito money) 
As 
Begin
    Begin try
        begin tran
        
            update Cuenta 
            set monto =  Isnull(monto,0) + @deposito;

        commit tran;
    end try
    begin catch
        if @@TRANCOUNT>0
            rollback tran;
        
        Print 'Error';
    end catch
end
```

Si observas el procedure, para saber si hay error o no, se utiliza un bloque tipo `try catch`, y en el se manejan los errores. Todo lo que ocurra en entre `begin try` y `end try`, significa que está bien, y por tanto se hace el `commit`. Todo lo que ocurra entre el `begin catch` y el `end catch` significa que va mal, y por tanto y siempre que haya una transacción abierta, se hace un `rollback`.

Por tanto la sentencia update actualiza la tabla `cuenta`, estableciendo en la columna `monto` lo que contuviese, más lo que le llega en el parámetro.

Por si hubiera un null, utilizamos la función isNull para que la suma se pueda realizar, ya que `Null` + lo que sea es `Null`

[image: Res1]

Si ejecutas el procedimiento.

```
exec deposito 10000;
exec deposito 20000;
```

[image: Res2]

Pero si la cuenta tiene más de una fila.

```
insert into Cuenta 
values
(2,null);

exec deposito 10000;
```

[image: res2]

Las dos cuentas se ven afectadas por el procedimiento, por tanto el procedimiento debería de recibir un parámetro que le indicase la cuenta, y aplicar la update solo a esa cuenta.

```
create or alter proc deposito 
(
  @deposito money
, @cuenta int
) 
As 
Begin
    Begin try
        begin tran
        
            update Cuenta 
            set monto =  Isnull(monto,0) + @deposito
            Where id = @cuenta;
            

            if @@ROWCOUNT =0
            begin
                Raiserror  (N'No se ha encontrado la cuenta. ',11,1);
            end
        commit tran;
    end try
    begin catch
        if @@TRANCOUNT>0
            rollback tran;
        DECLARE @ErrorMsg NVARCHAR(4000);  
        DECLARE @ErrorSvr INT;  
        DECLARE @ErrorStS INT;  
   
        SELECT  
            @ErrorMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),  
            @ErrorSvr = ERROR_SEVERITY(),  
            @ErrorStS = ERROR_STATE();  
 
        RAISERROR (@ErrorMsg,   
                   @ErrorSvr,
                   @ErrorStS 
                   );  
        
    end catch
end
```

Además ahora tienes un error lógico por la inexistencia de la cuenta, y utilizamos raiserror para dar el mensaje de salida que queramos. Al no tener filas `@@rowCount`, sabemos que no ha podido realizar la update porque no ha encontrado la cuenta. Devolvemos usando un error personalizado el mensaje y que se va al bloque catch. En el catch capturamos los mensajes y tipos y lo devolvemos al solicitante.

Nota: No se ha encontrado la cuenta, no es el mensaje correcto para no haber actualizado ninguna fila, pero esta puede ser una forma de hacerlo. También podrías hacer lo mismo, antes de la update para devolver mensajes, validando si los parámetros son adecuados, o si la cuenta existe, etc....

En ejecución:

```
exec deposito 10000, 3
```

[image: Res4]

```
exec deposito 10000, 1 

select * 
    from cuenta
       Where id  = 1;
```

[image: res5]

[RaisError](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/05/15/raiserror-como-funciona-como-se-utiliza/)

[IsNull](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/17/isnull-una-de-las-funciones-mas-usadas/)

[RowCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

[Try Catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)